# Help solving $f(\sin(x))=\sin(xy)$ for $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, problem-solving

I have worked with trigonometric functions at a high school level, but I have not really worked with functional equations or trig functions enough to know how to solve this myself. Is there some rule for this situation? Any hints or  solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $y$ here?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan $y$ is another function I'm going to be multiplying by $x$ within the brackets of the sine function. But it can be anything really.

Comment: So it is a variable and not a constant? That clears things up.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help but you can try writing $x$ as $a+b$ and $y$ as $a-b$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, interesting idea, how would that help? Is it because there are trig laws for $\sin(a\pm b)$?

Comment: I am not too sure it will be useful but:
$f\big(\sin (x)\big)=\sin (xy)$, so for starters $f(0)=0$.

Now, let $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$.  

$f\big(\sin (a+b)\big)=\sin (a^2-b^2)$  
$f\big(\sin (a)\cos (b) + \cos (a)\sin (b)\big)=\sin (a^2)\cos(b^2)+ \cos (a^2)\sin (b^2)$

Comment: If it was $f(x,y)$ instead, $f(x,y)=\sin \big( y\arcsin x \big)$ works.

Comment: You can delete your own question. No need to write closed

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I cannot, there is an answer.

Comment: Why not just revise the question so that it is specific enough?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  OP has specified so.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f( \sin x)= \sin (x y) $$

In a bounded argument:

$$ x\rightarrow \arcsin x $$
$$ f(x)= \sin (y\cdot  \arcsin x ) $$

$f(x) $ cannot be solved out analytically from implicit form.

Comment: The title specifically said to solve for $f(x)$. Not $y$.

Comment: Not clear. I understood $y$ in $f(x)$ form.

Comment: @MicahWindsor can you post the problem exactly as you found it? I feel like there must be something else that explains how to solve for $f(x)$ that you may have forgotten to mention.

Answer (score 0):

If $y$ is an integer, then $\sin (xy)$ is a polynomial in $\sin x$ and $\cos x,$ so that if we set $z=\sin x,$ then we obtain that $f(z)$ is a sum of powers of $z.$ That is, a linear combination of expressions of the form $z^m(\sqrt{1-z^2})^n$, where $m,n$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: But is $y$ an integer?

Comment: Thanks, but $y$ is not necessarily an integer. In my specific problem, $$y=\frac{m^6-1}{n^2-1}$$ and $$x=\pi m$$, $m,n\in\Bbb{R}$. But I am looking for a general solution, which is why I did not mention these in the post.

Comment: @MicahWindsor You should have mentioned, or at least excluded the case where $y$ is integral.